# Google universal analytics Ecommerce additional info

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics

I send a various information according to the [Ecommerce tracking protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce), particularly info for [additem()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#addItem). Some of the information is category for each item, but the google analytics only shows `name`, `product revenue`, and `quantity`.

How can I obtain what category and other info i originally sent via the tracking protocol?

Also, for some records the information is not showing at all, even if the graph indicates that there is. This disappearing act occurs sometimes when I'm trying to reverse a transaction as per https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en

[image]

Example code for one transaction (sensitive data altered):

```
<!-- thingy -->
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-mytrackingcode-3','auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {'id': '100007606',
    'affiliation' : 'mystorename', 
    'revenue': '-172.40', 
    'shipping':'-44.40', 
    'tax':'-10.24' });
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {'id': '100007606',
    'name' : 'Soft Wallet', 
    'sku': 'KB-GS0513-10', 
    'category':'', 
    'price':'128.00', 
    'quantity':'-1' });
ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
<!-- thingy -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Product category, and other things like variant and brand, are attributes of enhanced ecommerce. At least from the resource you linked to, it looks like you are using standard ecommerce tracking.

Comment: so then i provided that information to standard ecommerce tracking. How does google handle that? Ignored? 

I'm also trying to reverse the transaction by providing identical data, but negative according to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en What i've noticed that all data becomes invisible. 

I''ll update the OP

Comment: category is part of standard ecommerce now https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce I'm using only those fields listed in that guide. But the dashboard, for items, only shows name, price, quantity... and not SKU or category (see pic in OP)

Comment: Did you set the category value? Can you post your transaction and item code? Google ignores values that don't apply, so including the variant and brand.

Comment: That's good info that google ignores values that don't apply. i have category set to a blank string. i'll update the OP with a sample script, with info blanked out.

Comment: Might that explain why you don't see Category info, if you're not populating that field?

Comment: but i'm populating sku, and there is no column for sku either

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom left of the graph, there is a selectbox labeled "secondary dimension" Click that, then click the "ecommmerce" option, and you will be able to choose sub-options that correspond to product data, which will correspond to showing it in a column.